# Styling the first item in a css column

Tags: css

I have a list which is displayed over multiple columns. Each of the list items is block element (display:block) and has some styling attached to it (a 1px border at the bottom). It currently looks like this:

```
List item    List item    List item
---------    ---------    ---------
List item    List item    List item
---------    ---------    ---------
List item    List item
---------    ---------
```

I would like to add an identical border to the top of the first item in each column e.g.

```
---------    ---------    ---------    
List item    List item    List item
---------    ---------    ---------
List item    List item    List item
---------    ---------    ---------
List item    List item
---------    ---------
```

I've tried :first-line and ::first-line, neither of which seem to anything in this instance (probably because it doesn't work on block elements?)

The list may vary in length so I have no way to determine how many items will be in each column so I can't user :nth-of-type() either.

Does anybody know if this can be done (or conversely if it definitely can't?)

**My HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

**My CSS**

```
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 21px;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 21px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 21px;
    column-gap: 21px;
  }
  li {
    display: block;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -mx-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    padding: 1em 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Is it multiple lists next to each other or all one list throughout 3 columns?

Comment: Will you always have a 3 column stack or will it vary between resolutions?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia It will be a maximum 4 column stack based off his CSS but if the list isnt full it wont be all four columns

Comment: Francisco - Yes it liable to change the number of columns for different resolutions, sorry - I should have mentioned that

Comment: You mention you don't know how many elements you will have in your list; how is the list generated?

Comment: Sunyatasattva - it's part of a navigation

Comment: I mean, it is generated server-side or client side? Does it require user interaction (can users add or remove from the list) or will it stays this way?

Comment: it's generated server side - user won't need to edit it. I have no way to change the output - I'm just styling the output.

Comment: The correct property name is `break-inside`, `column-break-inside` is the name that appears in older drafts.  While some browsers do support it, it will be phased out eventually.  Firefox doesn't support either one, opting to use `page-break-inside` instead for this purpose.

Comment: Done with pure CSS! Please review my answer. It took me about 1 hour to complete it, but I really liked the challenge so went through it gladly and learned a lot (:

Answer (score 6):

Edit after seeing the code and 1 hour later: **DONE! With pure CSS!**

It took me a real while since I didn't want to use javascript. Here's a demos of what's really going on behind the scenes http://jsfiddle.net/mEtF6/1/, and here's the working version: **http://jsfiddle.net/mEtF6/2/**. If you don't understand anything, feel free to ask about it, since it's not very well documented. I had to actually add a div wrapping the 'ul' because the `overflow: hidden` on `ul` wouldn't behave as the `border-top` is outside the element. This is the working code:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">List item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">List item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">List item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">List item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">List item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="">List item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="">List item 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="">List item 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="">List item 9</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
div {
  /* This will hide the white space at the right (blue in the explanation) */
  overflow: hidden;
  }

ul {
  position: relative; /* Needed to place the :before pseudo element in the proper position */
  list-style: none;
  border-top: 1px dotted #000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-gap: 20px;
  }

/* This 'cuts' the top margin of ul so it's displayed in the same way as the other */
ul:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;

  /* Put the gaps on the <ul> top margin */
  top: -1px;

  /* Background-size = 1/4 of the width + 1/4 of the space between columns */
  background-size: calc(25% + 5px) 1px;

  /* Or it will hide the border-top of the ul */
  background-color: transparent;

  /* The actual white gaps at the top */
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    transparent calc(100% - 20px), /* All the <li> width minus the gap is transparent */
    red 20px);  /* Those 20px are white */
  }

li {
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -mx-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  }

/* This will hide the top margin of the last columns without elements */
li:last-child:before {
  position: absolute;
  /* You want to place the top  */
  margin-left: calc(25% + 5px);
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  top: -1px;
  width: 100%;
  }

/* Make the <a> fill the whole space of the <li> */
li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 0;
  }
```

Note: I added proper support for the `<a>` tags, making the whole block clickable, and not only the text inside it. You can ofc reverse it.

Note 2: <strike>tested only with **FIREFOX**. You might need to add some other -webkit gradients to make it cross-browser. Sorry but I'll leave this dirty work to you (;</strike> I found an apparent bug and asked a [question here in SO about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19302836/938236).

Again, the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mEtF6/2/.

Comment: +1 This is also a very good idea if you don't need a margin between your column borders.

Comment: I was thinking of maybe compromising with this, but it isn't the look I was going for really

Comment: @HeinA.Grønnestad I just saw that he wants a margin between column borders... working on it on jsfiddle. BTW, +1 but there's not +1? ):

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Haha, I forgot ;)

Comment: An alternative would be a repeating background on UL top aligned.. Not as elegant with css, but...

Comment: I could achieve it with pure CSS, it will behave with any list length you throw at it (:

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in some cases in firefox. Just try to add some more li items with different and long text and resize it to a quiet small viewport. You will notice, that `column-break-inside` or just `break-inside` is ignored and borders from li items of the first column are displayed in the sescond column.

Answer (score 5):

add `border-top: 1px dotted #000;
    margin-bottom: -1px;` to your li style

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kVZq/)

Comment: I tried that, and it works great in Chrome, but in Firefox the overlapping borders were offset by a pixel, so it was one solid line!

Comment: What version of FF are you on? I'm on the Mac and it's looks ok.

Comment: BUT - if I add a background colour to the li that problem doesn't occur! I'm going to do some browser testing, but this may be the solution

Comment: Using `margin-top: -1px` also works:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/lszgqgcw.  Not sure what the deal is with Firefox making some of the borders solid.

Answer (score 2):

If it's the same `ul` that's spanned across multiple columns and the number of items in the columns can vary. Then I can't see a way to do this. Not with CSS only at least.

I would make the columns a fixed number of items and use a `:nth* pseudo selector` or split the columns into different `ul` tags and style the first `li`.

If you want to use jQuery or similar you could maybe target the first `li`, find the `top` position of it and iterate through the others and if the `top` position matches add the border.

### Edit

This JSFiddle is one solution, but it does use jQuery though:

http://jsfiddle.net/8ZRkG/

With four columns:
[image]

With three columns:
[image]

Comment: I prefer to avoid js if I can for layout but it certainly does solve the problem +1 (and maybe a tick if nothing better pops up)

Answer (score 1):

The way the CSS3 multi-column model works is by creating a new type of container between the **content-box** and the **content**, called the **column box**.

Unfortunately, the [current spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#the-multi-column-model) explicitly states:

> It is not possible to set properties/values on column boxes. For example, the background of a certain column box cannot be set and a column box has no concept of padding, margin or borders.

Hence, at the present moment, **there is no selector** for the column boxes or the elements within, though the same page opens to the possibility that such a thing might be included in the future (why they didn't think of including it in the present spec, is beyond me).

Since you state you cannot edit the server-side output, you need to use Javascript. I see one solution already proposes that, though I disagree with the approach of calculating the top position of `li:first-child`. Instead, I propose this:

```
var liNum  = $('ul.columns li').length; // This computes the number of list items
var colNum = 4;                        // This is the number of columns you want

$('ul.columns li').each(function(i) {
    if ( i % Math.ceil(liNum/colNum) === 0 ) {
        $(this).addClass('top');
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**Working demo**](http://jsbin.com/oMihUTA/1/)</kbd>

Sure, it's a bit longer, but doesn't rely on the **computed top position** (which is a visual property) or on the `li` being **`:first-child`**. Instead, it relies on the number of elements that are in the list, which I think is the important number.

Of course, this is assuming you know how many columns you have (as you said you do). If you want to not rely on that piece of information, you can just compute that CSS instead:

```
var colNum = $('ul.columns').css('column-count')
```

Also, if you just want to add the border to the top, and don't want to style anything else, I would perhaps edit the css directly through the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method instead of adding a class. If you need to target the top element for more styles or other purposes (further JS for example), then I would add the class. But that's really a matter of preference.

Comment: As for why they might not have included it -- Allowing different styles for the first element by column position (as opposed to index in the HTML) would require calculating serially each element in a list whose elements used that selector.  That immediately rules out a lot of neat optimizations (mostly involving parallelism) so I can see why they'd be hesitant to do it, especially since lists can perfectly validly have a lot of elements.

Comment: Also looking to do this thing, and reading this I realize that being allowed to style the element at the top of the column may change it's size, reflowing the columns and changing which element is there, thus changing the styles and thus reflowing... this seems tricky

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming into this now, it is still not possible with just CSS, for good reasons.

Imagine what `ul > li:top-of-column { height: 500px }` would do. (It would change which element `:top-of-column` matches, and have a different element change height, which would change which element `:top-of-column` matches.. etc etc.

But changing some cosmetic detail like asked about above should be fine (but keep in mind that adding a 1px border makes the element 1px higher and could potentially change which element is in which column).

I ended up solving this with a little bit of javascript that also redoes it when the containing element changes size:

```js
const columns = document.querySelector("ul");

markTopsAndBottoms(columns);

/**
 * Removes all classes `className` from all children of `scope`
 * @param {string} className
 * @param {HTMLElement} scope
 */
function removeClass(className, scope) {
    for (const el of scope.querySelectorAll(`.${className}`)) {
        el.classList.remove(className);
    }
}
/**
 * Marks the top elements in all columns with the class `top-of-col`
 * and all bottom elements in all columns with the class `bottom-of-col`
 * @param {HTMLElement} cols the element that has its children in columns
 */
function markTopsAndBottoms(cols) {
    function doIt() {
        removeClass("top-of-col", cols);
        removeClass("bottom-of-col", cols);
        /** @type {NodeListOf<HTMLElement>} */
        const top = cols.querySelectorAll(":scope > *");
        let last = Infinity;
        top.forEach(el => {
            if (el.offsetTop <= last) {
                el.classList.add("top-of-col");
            }
            last = el.offsetTop;
        });
        /** @type {NodeListOf<HTMLElement>} */
        const bottom = cols.querySelectorAll(":scope > :has(+ .top-of-col), :scope > :last-child");
        bottom.forEach(el => {
            el.classList.add("bottom-of-col");
        });
    }
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(doIt);
    resizeObserver.observe(cols);
}
```

```css
ul {
  columns: 3;
  border: 1px dotted green;  
  margin: 5em;
  padding: 2em;
}
li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-inline: 1em;
}
/* This is needed to keep elements always the same height 
   so that it doesn't reflow from styling the top! */
li:not(.top-of-col) {
  padding-top: 1px;
}
li.top-of-col {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
li.bottom-of-col {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
      <li>item5</li>
      <li>item6</li>
      <li>item7</li>
      <li>item8</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Beware of how columns work with wrapping though. It differs in very significant ways between Firefox and Chrome/Safari. In Firefox, the elements are moved to their new position and you can move children out of them. In Safari and Chrome, the elements are moved to their new positions, but elements are stuck in some weird column space where they will wrap over to other columns. Look at this to see what I mean: https://codepen.io/einarmagnus/pen/YzgOOPX
Hover over the top elements to see differences in Safari and Chrome. Chrome is super weird, wrapping absolute offsets but not relative.