# :last-child:before with column-count behaving differently in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, browser, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

### The expected behaviour (Firefox)

[image: The expected behaviour]

### The unexpected (Chrome)

[image: The wrong behaviour]

### The JSFiddle demo

http://jsfiddle.net/bZaKK/ (try it in Firefox and Chrome to see the difference).

### The HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item 2</a></li>
  ...
  <li><a href="">List item 9</a></li>
</ul>
```

### The CSS

```
ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  }

li:last-child:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 1px;
  top: -1px;
  width: 100%;
  }
```

### The question

**Why is this happening and how can I fix it with pure CSS?** Is it a firefox bug or chrome bug?

Note: I found this *apparent* bug while answering this question: [Styling the first item in a css column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19300024/938236).

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is actually giving the proper behaviour. The unordered list is given `position:relative`, so the line will be positioned `absolute`, `relative` to ul.

Adding `left:0` to `li:last-child:before` will give the same behaviour in firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/bZaKK/2/

Comment: Yes, but the horizontal position, if `left` is left at `auto`, should remain where it was if it hadn't been positioned.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `relative` to `li`? I find oddly enough in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZaKK/3/) that if `li` has `display: inline`, the last-child:before is positioned absolute to ul, but if it has `display: inline-block;`, it behaves as relative to that li

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia The li has no position relative, so why should it be there? Absolute always goes to the first relative element

Comment: I don't know why, that's why I'm asking this... just try it yourself:
[display:inline fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZaKK/4/), [display:inline-block fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZaKK/3/).

Comment: It looks like chrome treats the list as a single column one and renders the pseudo-element based on that, and then does the modification of `column-count`, changing it's position.